# How does "for (i <- 1 to x; j <- 1 to y)" actually increment the variables in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, for-loop

How is below loop being incremented ?

```
for(i <- 1 to 3; j <- 1 to 3) print((10 * i + j) + " ")
```

Is there an implicit counter using 'to' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala, the `for` construct is like the "foreach" construct in Java.  The following sets `i` to be each successive item in the given Iterable.

```
scala> for(i <- Seq(1, 2, 3)) println(i)
1
2
3
```

The `to` operator, as in `1 to 3` constructs a `Range` from 1 to 3:

```
scala> 1 to 3
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: +1. The import thing to note (wrt "implicit counter using to") is that the expression `Int to Int` creates a Range. (There is an implicit conversion from `Int` -> `RichInt` so the method is actually [`RichInt.to(Int)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/RichInt.html). There is no magic, outside of the tricks of Scala.)

Answer (score 9):

`for` is actually shorthand for applying a bunch of collections methods.  In particular, if you are not using `yield`, each statement in the `for` selector is translated to `foreach`.  So

```
for (i <- 1 to 3; j <- 1 to 4) f(i,j)
```

turns into

```
(1 to 3).foreach{ i => (1 to 4).foreach{ j => f(i,j) } }
```

`foreach` is a method on all collections--`Range` included, which is what `1 to 3` turns into--which loops through each item in the collection, calling a provided function each time.  A `Range`'s items are the numbers listed (endpoints included, in this case)--in fact, `Range` doesn't actually store the numbers in a separate list, so it's main purpose is precisely to hold ranges of numbers for exactly this sort of iteration.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit conversion from Int to RichInt.

RichInt defines the function to() which returns a Range.

Range is a collection, and has foreach() hence it can be used in a for comprehension (which is just syntactic sugar for foreach()).